# AddQueryParameter using AddObject with null values

Tags: .net-core, restsharp

In [section](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#get-or-post) about parameters, there's a paragraph that allows to use `AddObject` instead of several `AddParameters`:

```
var params = new {
    status = 1,
    priority = "high",
    ids = new [] { "123", "456" }
};
request.AddObject(params);
```

There are two questions:

1. Is it possible to use for query parameters?
2. What will be if there is null value? Exception? Just not added query parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on my questions:

1. If the developer makes GET request, it will treat it as query parameters by default. If the developer makes POST request, it will work as `AddParameter`, hence developer should use `AddQueryParameter`.
2. If in an anonymous object you have null value, it will be ignored and not added to parameter.